# How to recover deleted items in Google Site List Items

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently created a new Item List page in google site for getting user details from members.  It was wonderful, and users can add a new item entering their details.

But what i found was that any one can edit any list item, and delete it.  In case of deleting, i could not find any option to recover deleted list.  The revision history does not exist for list items.

Could any one please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately recovering deleted list items isn't possible in Google Apps Script. One workaround could be to also store the content in ScriptDb, so that you can later recreate the list item if you desire.